# wchar and stdout in VC11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've found a weird issue with outputting wide chars in Visual Studio 2012 which I've narrowed down to the following code.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
  fputws(L"Hello World\n", stdout); // Throws Access Violation exception
}
```

When compiling this with Visual C++ 2012 it throws an "Unhandled exception", "Access violation reading location 0x00000064", somewhere inside `fputws`.

What I'm using to compile is with is the CLI version, just to rule out any settings in the IDE. I am opening the Visual Studio Command Prompt and using the following:

```
cl test.cpp
```

When using Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio 2010 it works well, writing out "Hello World".

But when using Visual Studio 2012, it crashes with the above mentioned error.

I have a hard time believing it's a compiler issue but rather something that's changed between the different versions of C++.

Another (funny) thing is that if I output a normal `char` first, like the code snippet below, it works just fine. So what I think is that it is an issue with uninitialized streams?

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
  fputs("", stdout);
  fputws(L"Hello World\n", stdout); // Now this works.
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit:

The following, similar, functions works fine in VS2012:

```
std::wcout << L"Hello world" << std::endl;
wprintf(L"Hello world\n");
_putws(L"Hello\n", stdout);
putwchar(L'H');
```

Edit 2:
Just filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772585/fputws-yields-access-violation) to microsoft.

Comment: The original issue is inside the logging framework LOG4CXX, which uses fputws. And besides that, I'd like to know what's wrong so I can avoid it in the future. :-)

Comment: sure, just wondering; I have no idea about your issue, do you get the same problem with `wprintf` and `putwchar` ?

Comment: Interestingly, the following commands works: std::wcout, wprintf, _putws, putwchar.

Comment: send your simplified test case to your compiler vendor.

Comment: Had exactly the same issue 2 days ago. Didn't make any sense of it, as you did when I tried outputting only a single character it works...
But anyway, log4cxx crashed on another stuff later on (mismatch between runtime libraries I guess, but couldn't figure it out).

So I moved to log4cpp and it works like a charm. Can only recommend that!

Comment: The short workaround until SP1 comes out would then be to add a simple `fputs("", stdout);` at the beginning of the program. Ugly, but it makes it work.

Comment: Looks strange. Did you submit a bug report on it?

Comment: Just filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772585/fputws-yields-access-violation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem on a RTM VS2012 but didn't on VS2012 Update 1. After installing Update 1 on the problem system the error disappeared. Thanks to Mats for reporting this.